# how to unit test in asp.net mvc the following code:

Tags: asp.net

how to unit test in asp.net mvc the following code:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Required Datatype>(new StreamReader(this.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd);
```

**i get null exception on this.Request**

Comment: Are you asking how to debug your code or are you asking how to write a unit test that identifies a null exception?

Comment: how to write unit test case for this code

Comment: so that i can overcome null exception

Comment: test cases do not overcome exceptions. They test for them and indicate whether they passed or failed. If you are trying to solve the error (forget about test cases) then you need to dig into the error - there will be more information further in. Also tag your question with the language (C#? VB?)